# выводит ошибку, не знаю что делать. Нужно вывести два массива

Tags: java

```
public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] massiv = new int[3];
        String[] city = {"Казань", "Мельбрун", "Москва", "Питер"};
        int mass = new massiv[4];
        massiv[3] = 23;
        massiv[2] = 34;
        massiv[1] = 45;
        massiv[0] = 56;
        System.out.println();
        String[] cityl = {"Камчатка", "Дубай", "Токио",};
        int ff = new massiv[3];
        massiv[2] = 13;
        massiv[1] = 14;
        massiv[0] = 15;
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i > city.length; i++){
            System.out.println();

        }
for(int i = 0; i > cityl.length; i++){
    System.out.println();
}
    }
```

Comment: Вместо i > city.length поставить i < city.length?

Comment: у меня "massiv" выводится красным

Comment: если вам нужно вывести 2 массива, то зачем вы пытаетесь объявить 5? зачем переменные massiv , mass , ff , если фактически вам нужны только city, city1?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] massiv = new int[4];
    String[] city = {"Казань", "Мельбрун", "Москва", "Питер"};
    int[] mass = new int[4];
    massiv[3] = 23;
    massiv[2] = 34;
    massiv[1] = 45;
    massiv[0] = 56;
    System.out.println();
    String[] cityl = {"Камчатка", "Дубай", "Токио",};
    int[] ff = new int[3];
    massiv[2] = 13;
    massiv[1] = 14;
    massiv[0] = 15;
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(city));

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cityl.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cityl));
    }
}
```

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать, но по крайней мере исправил очевидные ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] massiv = new int[4];
            String[] city = {"Казань", "Мельбрун", "Москва", "Питер"};
            int[] mass = new int[4];
            massiv[3] = 23;
            massiv[2] = 34;
            massiv[1] = 45;
            massiv[0] = 56;
            System.out.println();
            String[] cityl = {"Камчатка", "Дубай", "Токио",};
            int[] ff = new int[3];
            massiv[2] = 13;
            massiv[1] = 14;
            massiv[0] = 15;
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(city[i]);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < cityl.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(cityl[i]);
            }
        }}
```

Comment: чтобы создать 2 массива и вывести их в консоль , достаточно сделать так: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String[]{"Казань", "Мельбрун", "Москва", "Питер"})); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String[]{"Камчатка", "Дубай", "Токио"}));

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]